# When to invalidate Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

My activity uses a `FragmentPagerAdapter` that creates a new instance of my `Fragment` from the  `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()` method.

Whenever I select the page containing my fragment of interest, I want to update its views because they may have been invalidated in the meantime when this page wasn't on screen.

What is the correct moment/method to do this? I've tried a few things:

- MyFragment.onCreateView: this is only called the first time
- PagerAdapter.onPageSelected: since the `PagerAdapter` creates new instances all the time, field references to `Views` obtained with `findViewById` in `onCreateView` are unavailable (unless they're static members I guess).
- The other lifecycle events including `onResume`, `onAttach`

I found that if I pass the `Activity` reference to the `Fragment` from the `onPageSelected` event, and use `findViewById` on that to obtain new references to my Views it works, but I can't imagine there isn't a more intended way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OverRide this method, `setUserVisibleHint` Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment instance state save and restore. Whenever it is true then that means the fragment is being viewed, either from a view pager or something triggering the validation of its views. 
An app may set this to false to indicate that the fragment's UI is scrolled out of visibility or is otherwise not directly visible to the user.

M[ore info:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint())

Comment: add some logic and manipulate that method to achieve your goals!